# How to implement unix command "who" in c with all the options?

Tags: unix, command

I have been trying to implement the unix command "who" in c. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <utmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct utmp *n;
    char *a;
    int i;
    setutent();
    n=getutent();
    while(n!=NULL)
    {
        if(n->ut_type==7)
        {
            printf("%-9s",n->ut_user);
            printf("%-12s",n->ut_line);
            a=ctime(&n->ut_time);
            printf(" ");
            for(i=4;i<16;i++)
                printf("%c",a[i]);
            printf(" (");
            printf("%s",n->ut_host);
            printf(")\n");
        }
        n=getutent();
    }
}
```

This code only gives me the "who" implementation. I need this along with all the options of "who" command like
-a
-b
-p
-d
-H
--count
-q
etc .
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: parse comand line options http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments

Comment: @AmitG  I did that but i am not able to implement the options such as "-b" . "-b" gives the last boot time of the system. How can i implement that in C ?

Comment: Download the source code for `who` and look at how it does the things you want to do...

Comment: @twalberg I am not able to find the source code. Can u please send the link ?

Comment: In Linux, it's part of the `coreutils` package. You don't specify what OS you're using, so I can't tell you any more than that...

Comment: @twalberg I'm using ubuntu 14.04(OS)